# detecting touch events on UIWebview?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

i am loading a image onto my uiwebview and when the user clicks the image i have a link which i want the user to be redirected to but i am not able to find  any solution regarding it??

i tried to use

> - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest

but it can only be for links and not for a image as when i touch the image nothing happens?? is there any other possible way??

Comment: Do you have control of the HTML being loaded into the web view? You could put an a tag around the image and that would link the web view wherever you wanted it to go.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just wrap the image with a link tag in the HTML?